# Django: How to Edit Page with Foreign Key Field set (Unable to edit and post to models)

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I am trying to edit a django database via html form. However I am unsure why the following error is appearing. The product category is a foreign key and I can't change it's value. How can I solve the error? Thank you.

> ValueError at /shop/polyester-cushions/eiffel/edit_product/ Cannot
>   assign "'Polyester Cushions'": "Product.category" must be a "Category"
>   instance.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

class Product(models.Model):    
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ("Cotton Cushions", "Cotton Cushions"),
        ("Polyester Cushions", "Polyester Cushions")
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

edit_product.html

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select name="category" class="form-control" value="{{ product.category }}">
            <option {% if product.category == "Cotton Cushions" %} selected {% endif %} value="Cotton Cushions">Cotton Cushions</option>
            <option {% if product.category == "Polyester Cushions" %} selected {% endif %} value="Polyester Cushions">Polyester Cushions</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/")
def EditProduct(request, c_slug, product_slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(category__slug=c_slug, slug=product_slug)
        error = ''
        if request.method == 'POST':
            product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
            if product_form.is_valid():
                product.save()
                return redirect('shop/my_products.html/')
            else:
                error = "Data is not valid"

        return render(request, 'shop/edit_product.html', {'product':product, 'error':error})
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Product

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name','slug','description','category','price','image','stock','available')
```

Comment: The value in that option is a string, and you're basically trying to insert a string into a ForeignKey field. Try setting the value to an ID and getting the model from the ID in the view.

Comment: Add your views.py as well and Form class code also if any to question

Comment: Wiggy: thank you. I see what you mean now.
Satendra: I've added them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ForeignKey` field don't pass `choices` attribute in it. The objects of `Category` model will behave as its choices.

**Remove the `choices` attribute from `category` field in `Product` model**

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

> Do not forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command after
>   removing `choices` from field

**In your template use `{{form}}` context variable inspite of manually rendering form**

And if you are manually rendering use `pk` of category object as options value. and loop over all category objects.

## UPDATE

Remove `c_slug` from url and modify your `EditProduct` view as

```
@login_required(login_url="/")
def EditProduct(request, product_slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        error = ''
        if request.method == 'POST':
            product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
            if product_form.is_valid():
                product_form.save()
                return redirect('shop/my_products.html/')
            else:
                error = "Data is not valid"
        else:
           # create and edit form when request is GET
           product_form = ProductForm(instance=product)

        # add `product_form` in context instead of `product`
        return render(request, 'shop/edit_product.html', {'product_form':product_form, 'error':error})
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

> Note: create edit `product_form` form when the request is GET and send
>   `product_form` in context instead of `product` to the template

And in `edit_product.html` just use below code for rendering form

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{product_form}}
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i'm sorry, I still don't get it all. How should the html part be written. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @moonfairy check the updated section in my answer, hope this helps

Comment: If you still don't get it, Create a repo on Github I will make changes to it directly.

Comment: hi satendra, sorry for the late reply. Following is the link to my github https://github.com/moonfairyz/sun
I'm also still working on it myself now. Thanks a tonne for the help!

Comment: what should go inside of here:
 form action="{%%}"

Comment: @ Satendra, I've got it, I just removed the: action="{%%}"
and it works now. Super awesome! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

Usually the html is like this:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

models.py (You may need to run makemigrations and migrate)

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ("Cotton Cushions", "Cotton Cushions"),
        ("Polyester Cushions", "Polyester Cushions")
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py (or you can use django's UpdateView)

```
@login_required(login_url="/")
def EditProduct(request, c_slug, product_slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(category__slug=c_slug, slug=product_slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('shop/my_products.html')
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=product)
    return render(request, 'shop/edit_product.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: i'm sorry i tried it but it doesn't work, it doesn't solve the html part yet which is passing in string into foreign key field, i'm a beginner. Thanks for your help

Comment: @moonfairy see `django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView`

Answer (score 0):

Please check Your Product table category field name in database. Its a ForeignKey. Its can change filed name like adding category_id.